# ForEach Loop JSON AngularJS Object in Object

Tags: angularjs, json

I am very new to AngularJS and I am trying to learn how to get deeper into a JSON object that has objects inside of objects and sometimes even arrays. This is a "simplified" version I am working with and I hope it will help me get a basic understanding so I can do the rest on my own.

**json**

```
 values =      {
          "profile": {
            "fields": {
              "number-of-fields": "700",
              "inside": [
                "test1",
                "test2"
              ],
              "type": "test",
              "values": "450"
            }
          },
          "id": "12312312333645"
        }
```

**code**

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
 // I know I need to loop inside of each object I beleieve


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygahqdge/184/

Comment: Is `values.` a typo?

Comment: You can log the whole object to console. If you use f12 tool, you can browse the object in the browser.

Comment: values is a object..angular.foreEact works on arrays or array of objects.

Comment: I can't get your fiddle to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The basics**

Traverse object properties with a dot `.`, traverse array indexes with an index reference, `[0|1|2|etc.]`.

**What about your object?**

```
var yoObject = {
    "profile": {
        "fields": {
            "number-of-fields": "700",
            "inside": [
                "test1",
                "test2"
            ],
            "type": "test",
            "values": "450"
        }
    },
    "id": "12312312333645"
}
```

*Get the inside values:*

```
// object   object  object array
   yoObject.profile.fields.inside.map(console.log, console) // ["test1", "test2"]
```

*Get the id:*

```
// object   property
   yoObject.id // "12312312333645"
```

*Get all properties of the fields object:*

```
Object.keys(yoObject.profile.fields) // ['number-of-fields', 'inside', 'type', 'values']
```

*Get all values of the properies from above:*

```
fields = yoObject.profile.fields
Object.keys(fields).map(key => console.log(fields[key])) // ["700", ["test1", "test2"], "test", "450"] // Note: Order isn't guaranteed
```

Just play about with things. Throw the object in the console and start to manually traverse it. Then try to loop over things.

Have fun!

Note: I tested none of that! :P

> this is a question in regards on the right way to loop deep in JSON
>   objects – @user2402107

There's no *right* way. Sometimes you'll need to be fully dynamic, other times you can hardcode paths into nested properties and values.

*Fiddle-Diddle*

Nest as many times as you need:

```
angular.forEach(values, (value, key) => {
  console.log("Value for", key, ":", value);
  angular.forEach(value, (value, key) => {
    console.log("Value for", key, ":", value);
    angular.forEach(value, (value, key) => {
      console.log("Value for", key, ":", value);
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Adrian this is an excellent response but it doesnt really show me. Can you make an edit to my jsfiddle to show...

Comment: Added more code to the answer. You nest as deep as you need to. How deep do you wanna go?!

Comment: my clarity on this is a little poor... there is an overall JSON object that I am not showing these are however the values I need to parse out, the good thing is profile is the first object so the flow is the same..

Comment: what I am really looking for is on my Jfiddle to show a loop that logs every level and values at each level

Comment: Keep nesting the the loops and it'll get there.

Comment: can you show me how to at least get "number-of-fields" and the vaues the the "inside" array, and I can figure the rest out

Answer (score 0):

You can log the whole object to console. By using F12 tool, you can browse the object in the browser.

```
console.log(objectName);
```

Comment: I got that I have added a plunker to show what I mean, this is a question in regards on the right way to loop deep in JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

angular.forEach works on arrays. lets suppose you have an array of objects as this

```
var values = [{
  "profile": {
    "fields": {
      "number-of-fields": "700",
      "interpertation": [
        "whenever this is ready"
      ],
      "type": "test",
      "values": "450"
    }
  },
  "id": "12312312333645"
},
{
  "profile": {
    "fields": {
      "number-of-fields": "700",
      "interpertation": [
        "whenever this is ready"
      ],
      "type": "test",
      "values": "450"
    }
  },
  "id": "12312312333645"
}]
```

you can explore each object and its properties like this

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.profile.fields.values);



});
```

you can use `.` notation to access propertes